# Having clause using JPA Specifications

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to convert the below having clause to JPA Specifications as native query isn't an option here. Is it even possible? I've done some work as you can see below but not sure if I am on the right track. All help is appreciated.

```
 SELECT
   *
  FROM location
  HAVING     (
3959 * acos (
  cos ( radians(36.191577) )
  * cos( radians( lat ) )
  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(44.009585) )
  + sin ( radians(36.191577) )
  * sin( radians( lat ) )
))   < 10


 Specification<HouseProperty> havingClause = new Specification<HouseProperty>() {
                @Override
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<HouseProperty> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                    Join<Property, Location> propertyLocation = root.join("location", JoinType.INNER);


                    cb.function("cos", Double.class,
                        cb.function("radians", Double.class, propertyLocation.get("lat"))
                    ) ;

                    return null;
                }
            };

        }
```